# Getting multiple value from single cookie using php

Tags: php

I want to implement shopping cart in php. I am using single cookie to store multiple product id and quantity. Now i want to fetch these values from the cookies.
The data is stored in this format : {Product_id-Quantity}
Like this :
A-2,B-4,C-1,D-3
Now i want to use explode function to get these two values product id and quantity separately.
I do not know how to do this. Can anyone figure out a way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go - this saves your cookie-string in a PHP array:

```
$str = "A-2,B-4,C-1,D-3";

$arr = explode(",", $str);

foreach($arr AS $row)
{
    $piece = explode("-", $row);
    $cookie[$piece[0]] = $piece[1];
}
var_dump($cookie);
```

**notice:** your names and values must not contain `,` or `-` because you use them as separators.